matdatepicker is converting the string date will all ones to 11/11/1111
The matdatepicker is parsing or deserializing the date when entered in the input field as 11111111111111111111 to 11/11/1111. How to avoid doing this?

What do you want to happen instead?

Can you show your code with the expected output ?

Have you tried using its built-in validation properties: https://v18.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-validation

Which date adapter are you using? With the native date adapter I cannot reproduce this.

Yes with native date adapter it is working fine. I have moment dateadapter with that it does not work like that
